# yum Could not retrieve mirrorlist

Tags: centos6, yum

```
# yum clean all
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Cleaning repos: base extras updates
Cleaning up Everything
```

`yum info` got a timeout:

```
# yum --verbose info
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Not loading "fastestmirror" plugin, as it is disabled
Not loading "security" plugin, as it is disabled
Config time: 0.032
Yum Version: 3.2.29
Setting up Package Sacks
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=i386&repo=os error was
12: Timeout on http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=i386&repo=os: (28, 'connect() timed out!')
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: base. Please verify its path and try again
```

`ping` is OK:

```
# ping mirrorlist.centos.org
PING mirrorlist.centos.org (212.69.166.138) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from babylon.castlegem.co.uk (212.69.166.138): icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=344 ms
64 bytes from babylon.castlegem.co.uk (212.69.166.138): icmp_seq=2 ttl=46 time=342 m
```

`curl` is OK:

```
# curl 'http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=i386&repo=os'
http://centos.01link.hk/6.8/os/i386/
http://mirror.vpshosting.com.hk/pub/linux/centos/6.8/os/i386/
http://mirror.sunnyvision.com/centos/6.8/os/i386/
http://centos.uhost.hk/6.8/os/i386/
http://repo.virtualhosting.hk/centos/6.8/os/i386/
http://ftp.cuhk.edu.hk/pub/Linux/centos/6.8/os/i386/
http://centos.communilink.net/6.8/os/i386/
http://centos.nethub.com.hk/6.8/os/i386/
http://ftp.sjtu.edu.cn/centos/6.8/os/i386/
http://mirrors.btte.net/centos/6.8/os/i386/
```

How can I fix the timeout?

Comment: Check your proxy configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed after removing proxy settings in `/etc/yum.conf`.

Comment: Please accept your answer so the question gets marked as "solved" in the system.